# Problem with recognition awt and swing libraries during the coding

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, drop-down-menu, awt

Everything works in the program when the libraries with `import javax.swing.*` and `import java.awt.*`,but it doesn't work when something from these libraries is typed that doesn't offer awt and swing options in drop-down menu.

Example:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

    public class MainFrame extends JFrame{

        public static MainFrame instance = null;

        private MainFrame() {
            inicijalizacija();
        }

        private void inicijalizacija() {

            Toolkit kt=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
            Dimension velicina=kt.getScreenSize();
            int visina=velicina.height;
            int sirina=velicina.width;

            setSize(visina/2,sirina/2);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
            setTitle("GeRuDok"); 
        }

        public static MainFrame getInstance() {
            if(instance==null) {
                instance=new MainFrame();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
```

e.g Toolkit cannot be released here as awt, but offers it as com.sun.javafx.tk and like others(Dimension,getScreenSize...)

I thought it had something to do with the content assistant, but it doesn't work either.
It may have something to do with the Java version 1.8 that the project is in, but I really have no idea how to fix it.

I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Its not quite clear what you are trying to ask, but I assume you have some issues with your imports? However the code you provided should compile just fine, so it might be related to your IDE.

Comment: I think it has something to do with your IDE that you mistakenly selected the [Open JDK's Toolkit](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~ant/RT-27887/webrev.2/javafx-ui-common/src/com/sun/javafx/tk/Toolkit.java.html) instead of the [AWT version](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html) for the `Toolkit` class. Without knowing which IDE you're using, we cannot provide further assistance

Comment: It works great, it just never offers awt and swing components in the drop-down menu,and I don't know how I would install the IDE to make it work?

Comment: The version is Version: 2019-09 R (4.13.0)

Comment: Personally I still don't understand what the problem is. What exactly isn't working? What do you need to fix if this compiles fine and "works great"?

Comment: The problem is that Eclipse doesn't recognize imported libraries. For example, I don't have autocomplete for methods and classes from awt library, but I can use those functionalities if I enter it manually. So, autocomplete doesn't work properly. I checked out the settings for autocomplete and I reset it to defaults, but it's not working either.